# Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer download error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer edition, cannot find one or more components, please reinstall the application is the first message and then I reinstalled the application and the error message in installation tool is Missing or unspecified settings that were configured to default values: Service SID support has been enabled on the service. Service SID support has been enabled on the service. Please help me with installing Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Did you uninstall it first before reinstalling?

Comment: yes I have uninstalled everything using command prompt and deleted all source from my PC and I started downloading it from from starting and tried to reinstall it.

Comment: Do you have enough hard drive space to install it? I think it needs about 10GB

Comment: I have more than 100GB